# Error message when saving folder is not shown

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to package my app as a standalone where users just generate report and save in folders they want. However, I still can't figure out to pop up error message when no folder to save is selected:

```
from pathlib import Path

def errors(report, save_folder):
errors = False
error_message=[]

if (Path(report).suffix.upper()!='.CSV':
errors = True
error_message.append('Not CSV format')

if not (Path(save_folder)).exists():
errors = True
error_message.append('No folder selected')
```

I'm having problem with second one, where even though no folder is selected, I do not have the error message.

Any good suggestions please?

Comment: How are you displaying the errors? Are you using a `messagebox`?

Comment: Try to print out what the value of `save_folder`.  No folder selected may mean that `save_folder` is an empty string. So `Path(save_folder)` will return current working directory.

Comment: @jezza_99 yes bro, if `error` goes to `True`, the message box should pop up. It is working fine for 1st error option, but for 2nd not showing up

Comment: @acw1668 yes, it returns blank string. So I tried to set up error to:
`if save_folder=''` This thing never crosse my mind lol, thanks for suggestion

Comment: Is the indentation provided in the code of your question the same as the one you are using? If yes then it might be an issue with your indentation.